# how to create archieve file name as today-1 in nlog.config file

Tags: c#, nlog

If I use archivefileName as

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="FileLog" maxArchiveFiles="5" archiveEvery="Day" archiveFileName="${ProtocolLog}/Archives/${shortdate-TimeSpan.FromDays(1)}.txt" 
        layout="${baseLayout}" concurrentWrites="true" fileName="${ProtocolLog}/ProtocolLog.txt" encoding="utf-8" />
```

it is generated as follows.

> In Today,  2018-09-10.

I want to generate archieve file name as **2018-09-09**.

How can I create an earlier date in nlog.

Comment: no, It doesn't work. my file is nlog.config

Comment: how are you declaring short date?

Comment: umm, It is nlog default value as yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Does this help - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2224